# Integral $\int \frac{dx}{x^4+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Find $$\int \frac{dx}{x^4+1}$$

I found a possible solution to this question [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3he49YbzYvI)

However, I was wondering if there is a "nicer" solution, that would more understandable to a person who isn't advanced in complex numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: The link that you found addresses the definite integral (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$) and uses special techniques (residue calculus).

Answer (score 7):

All polynomials can be factors into linear and quadratic factors:

$$x^4 +1 = x^4 +2x^2 + 1 - 2x^2 = (x^2 + 1)^2 - 2x^2 = (x^2 + \sqrt 2 x +1)(x^2 - \sqrt 2 x +1)$$

Thus your integral can be found using partial fraction.

Comment: I was just typing the same answer, but you were faster. (+2)

Comment: Just wondering how you can +2? Um...... @mickep

Comment: Sorry, that was a small joke...

Comment: @john with teamwork, yes we can. :)